# Add a class to variable sub-pages in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I need to add a class to all subpages of `/career/jobs/` on my new WordPress project. 
I have already an import running, which imports all new jobs from my customer's HR programme to the website and creates portfolio items with them. So my link structure looks something like: `/career/jobs/219/`. Now I need to add to all subpages of `/jobs/` a class ( the subpage directory is variable, so just write for every new job a new line of code is nearly impossible ).

Do you have some code snippets for me, please? Can't find something online.

That's what I have so far:

```
$url = site_url( '/career/jobs/219/' );
<div class="<?php if($url == '/career/jobs/219/') echo 'mccom-job-container'; ?> ">
```

As you can see the code above only ads a class to one specific site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing site_url('/career/jobs/219/') which prints http://example.com/career/jobs/219/

and you are comparing like

> /career/jobs/219/ == http://example.com/career/jobs/219/

which is a wrong comparision

use `strpos` instead like below

```
$url = site_url( '/career/jobs/219/' );
<div class="<?php if (strpos($url, '/career/jobs/219/') != false) echo 'mccom-job-container'; ?> ">
```

strpos will compare the string which is present in the $url

Answer (score 0):

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

usually gives you everything you need...

It's generally best to add it to the body instead of an inner div too so it's available everywhere.